# node_modules/glob/dist/mjs/index"' has no exported member 'IOptions'. && Minipass type error

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install, glob

I am currently trying to upgrade glob from version 8.1.0 to 10.2.4 (as long as I have version 9.x.x or higher it's fine). @types/glob version is 8.1.0. When running `npm run build`, the following error comes:

```
PS > npm run build

> identity.service@1.0.0 build
> npm run compile && node infrastructure/build-api && node infrastructure/build-cf && npm run api-spec-check


> identity.service@1.0.0 compile
> tsc -p ./

infrastructure/copy-files.ts:15:27 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/YashRaniga/Documents/dev/identity-service/node_modules/glob/dist/mjs/index"' has no exported member 'IOptions'.

15     let globOptions: glob.IOptions = {};
                             ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/glob/node_modules/minipass/index.d.ts:148:3 - error TS2416: Property 'on' in type 'Minipass<RType, WType, Events>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Stream'.
  Type '<Event extends keyof Events>(ev: Event, handler: (...args: Events[Event]) => any) => this' is not assignable to type '(eventName: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void) => this'.
    Types of parameters 'ev' and 'eventName' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof Events'.
        Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof Events'.
          Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof Events<RType>'.

148   on<Event extends keyof Events>(
      ~~

node_modules/glob/node_modules/minipass/index.d.ts:153:3 - error TS2416: Property 'once' in type 'Minipass<RType, WType, Events>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Stream'.
  Type '<Event extends keyof Events>(ev: Event, handler: (...args: Events[Event]) => any) => this' is not assignable to type '(eventName: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void) => this'.
    Types of parameters 'ev' and 'eventName' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof Events'.
        Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof Events'.

153   once<Event extends keyof Events>(
      ~~~~

node_modules/glob/node_modules/minipass/index.d.ts:158:3 - error TS2416: Property 'addListener' in type 'Minipass<RType, WType, Events>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Stream'.
  Type '<Event extends keyof Events>(ev: Event, handler: (...args: Events[Event]) => any) => this' is not assignable to type '(eventName: string | symbol, listener: (...args: any[]) => void) => this'.
    Types of parameters 'ev' and 'eventName' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof Events'.
        Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof Events'.

158   addListener<Event extends keyof Events>(
      ~~~~~~~~~~~
        Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof Events'.

163   emit<Event extends keyof Events>(ev: Event, ...data: Events[Event]): boolean
      ~~~~


Found 5 errors in 2 files.

Errors  Files
     1  infrastructure/copy-files.ts:15
     4  node_modules/glob/node_modules/minipass/index.d.ts:148
```

Gone through multiple stack overflow threads, none of them have worked. Saw one thread where apparently @types/glob isn't required but removing that didn't work. Running `npm install minipass` also didn't fix the minipass errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob.IOptions` is no longer a thing. It's just GlobOptions, imported from the glob package.

The minipass error was fixed on the latest minipass version.